# Why is my code doesn't print the invalid value to inform the user?

Tags: c++

In this program I'm trying to print the single value which is identified as invalid by the program.
For example the any non-digit value is invalid and the program must print it along an error message which is defined.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Welcome();
void botVerification();
bool isNumber(string botV);
int main ()
{
    Welcome();
    botVerification();
    botVerification();
    botVerification();
    return 0;
}
void Welcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome to our program" << '\n';
}
void botVerification()
{
    string botV;
    cout << "Enter the number to start the Calculator: ";
    cin >> botV;
    if(isNumber(botV))
        cout << "Success" << '\n';
    else
        cout << "Not success " << '\n';
}
bool isNumber(string botV)
{
    int badIndex = 0;
    for (int bcounter = 0; bcounter < botV.length(); bcounter++)
        if (!(botV[bcounter] >=48 && botV[bcounter] <= 57))
            {
              return false;
              badIndex = bcounter;
              cout << "Not success " << botV[badIndex] << " is not a number "<< '\n';
              break;
            }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Your function `returns false` before it has a chance of invoking `cout`.

Comment: @raina77ow Appreciated )

Comment: What input did you try? @rainq77ow then the botVerification would print "Not success".

Comment: @raina77ow Please avoid answering questions in the comments section. Thanks.

Comment: @jjj in 123A the character A is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exits before it reaches the "cout" in your "bool".

```
bool isNumber(string botV)
{
    int badIndex = 0;
    for (int bcounter = 0; bcounter < botV.length(); bcounter++)
        if (!(botV[bcounter] >=48 && botV[bcounter] <= 57))
            {
              return false;
              badIndex = bcounter;
              cout << "Not success " << botV[badIndex] << " is not a number "<< '\n';
              break;
            }
        return true;
}
```

**Fix**

```
bool isNumber(string botV)
{
    int badIndex = 0;
    for (int bcounter = 0; bcounter < botV.length(); bcounter++)
        if (!(botV[bcounter] >=48 && botV[bcounter] <= 57))
            {
              badIndex = bcounter;
              cout << "Not success " << botV[badIndex] << " is not a number "<< '\n';
              break;
              return false;
            }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Look at the function `botVerification()` that invokes `isNumber`.